# Android logic error for media player object volume increase and decrease linearly

Tags: java, android, volume, android-mediaplayer

I wrote a program to increase volume and decrease, It is working randomly.Plz let me know the problem. i=50 default
u.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(i<=100&&j<=100)
            mp.setVolume(i+=10,j+=10);
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Max Obtained", 3);


        }
    });
    d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(i>=0&&j>=0)
            mp.setVolume(i-=10,j-=10);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Min Obtained", 3);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Mediaplayer.setVolume takes values from 0 to 1.0f . Your range seems to be 0 to 100.

Comment: cool. Thanks bro for d information. I was also able rectify d mistake in seekbar :D